# Change the group site's layout

Tags: sharepoint

I have admin rights to my own group's Sharepoint in our organization. The default layout has news, recent activities, documents, etc. Knowing we will not be posting news posts, I would like to have our **Documents** have the spotlight on our start page. How can I change the layout of our group's modules to reflect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These news, recent activities, documents, etc are web parts in the home page. You could just edit the home page and remove other web parts and only keep the documents web part.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Let me have a look and come back!

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Turns out my other admin colleague had the tab open and I could not do any changes. Now I can!